# Language on page is not showing up

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to create a page which displays the content in a different language how ever the content is displaying as only **???????** on the page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">
<head>
<title>Arabic Quran</title>
<meta name="Author" content="Mustafaa Hanafi"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="AR"/>
<meta name="Keywords" content="hadith bukhari, sahih Bukhari, the hadith of the prophet, ahadith, ahadees, hadees, hadist, saheeh bukhari, hadist bukhari, the hadith, bukhari hadith"/>
<meta name="Description" content="Sahih bukhari hadith narrations and translation in english, it is one the most authentic collection of hadith, view the hadith by narrator or search"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
```

I included this in the meta tag and if my reading on this tag is correct it should make it display the content in Arabic. I will provide a screenshot with my issue below.

[image]

Comment: it seems this tag is deprecated, take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: Are you reading this from a database or something?

Comment: @Musa yea could it be something with my database ?

Comment: There is where I'd look

Comment: The code in the question shows no content. Neither does it specify how the content gets inserted in the HTML document, and this appears to be the crucial issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the page Arabic vision of Quran add `lang="ar"` to the `html` tag like so

```
<html lang="ar">
...
</html>
```

or try this when first connect to your data base : `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`

```
$MySQL_Handle = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME) 
or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) ); 

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($MySQL_Handle,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase');
```

Comment: This is not working.. do I need to include something else? I am updating my post with my entire head tag.

Comment: can you provide a link to your website ?

Comment: you must set charset in first connect with mysql y this query:

SET CHARACTER SET utf8

Comment: are you sure you have motioned this  before insert and before select ??

Comment: you need to set charater set utf8 at the connection to the database befor any other select or insert

Comment: The `lang` attribute, though useful in principle, is irrelevant to this problem. Besides, the code in the question already contains it. So the answer starts in a misleading way. And it does not explicitly say the essential thing: use UTF-8 throughout.

Comment: i motioned this in the second part of my answer !!